# Collection findAllResults in Groovy 1.7.5

Tags: collections, groovy

Groovy 1.7.5 [claims](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4253) to have both `findResult` and `findAllResults`.  But when I try, it seems to have only `findResult`.  `findAllResults` is not included in the [groovy jdk documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/), either.  Am I not reading it thoroughly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the comments in that issue, ([Ted Naleid added a comment](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4253?focusedCommentId=225873&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#action_225873)  - 19/Jun/10 10:46 PM) says that findAllResults was removed as it can be easily achieved with an inject in it's place

Answer (score 3):

As a follow up, [this has been implemented as of Groovy 1.8.1 as `findResults`](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4899) instead of `findAllResults`.  It's cleaner than using `inject` in many situations.